# How does Tor browser protect against fraudulent pages?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, settings

The Tor browser has a setting in about:preferences#privacy to block dangerous and deceptive content. This includes blocking dangerous downloads and warning the user about unwanted and uncommon software. This setting is from Mozilla Firefox's settings. This setting is actually helpful in protecting the user's privacy and anonymity since scams attempting to expose the user's identity and personal information can be blocked. But I haven't heard or learned about more ways Tor blocks fraudulent websites in detail. Can someone experienced tell me any other ways the Tor browser blocks frauds and scams if they do so? Are there any other settings I can enable in the Tor browser to protect myself from scams and frauds?

Comment: what is a "fraudulent website"?

Comment: @user610620 websites that try to scam you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only extra feature that Tor Browser implements compared to Firefox to block fraudulent/hijacked webpages is the inclusion of the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extension, which forces HTTPS on some specific websites. This helps to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks such as SSL stripping which can show the attacker's webpage rather than the real webpage, but only on supported websites. This is enabled by default.

When using Tor Browser, you must still follow the usual browsing safety measures. For example, check the URL to make sure you're on the correct website and using HTTPS (especially when providing a password), don't follow links in emails, only download files from trusted sources, etc.

When using the Tor Browser, you should use the default settings unless you are sure that changing them won't be harmful. For example, enabling the "Block dangerous and deceptive content" setting may make you fingerprintable. [In Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work#w_how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work-in-firefox#w_how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work-in-firefox), enabling this setting may also send information about files you download and domain names that you visit to Mozilla and Google's servers. It's not clear to me if Tor Browser also does this when this setting is enabled.

Comment: i thought HTTPS is a service paid by a webmaster to a web hosting provider in order to SSL-encrypt their pages. How can a browser extension exert this ability as well, or how is it different than what the web hosts do?

Comment: The browser extension doesn't add HTTPS, it just enforces it. Most websites automatically redirect viewers who visit for example `http://mywebsite.com` to `https://mywebsite.com`, but a malicious server/router in the middle could remove the redirect and prevent you from using HTTPS. The extension forces the browser to use HTTPS for specific websites, even if someone tries to prevent it.